# Bootstrap grid, middle content stuck to top of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a CMS style html template so that a user can drop content into a template.

I'm using bootstrap grid to create the template but I'm having some issues.

Basically I'm shooting for a main body container, which has a sticky top, a sticky bottom, and then the main middle section filling the rest of the space which houses other areas.

IN this case, the middle section has 2 areas at 50%, one to the left and one to the right.

The problem is my middle section is currently stuck to the very top of the page along with the top section but I need it to fill up the middle the way that I've structured it but I"m not sure how I should change positioning.

Here's the current block:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,body{
      height:100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid" style="text-align: center; height:100%; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div class="row top"> 
      <div class="col-lg-12" style=" background-color: #A0A0A0;position: absolute; height: 15%;">
        <p style="color: white">Top</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row middle">
      <div class="col-lg-6" style=" background-color: #A0A0A0">
        <p style="color: white">Left</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="   background-color: #A0A0A0;">
        <p style="color: white">Right</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bottom">
      <div class="col-lg-12" style=" background-color: #A0A0A0; bottom:0; position: absolute; height: 10%;">
        <p style="color: white">Bottom</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it hard on yourself. Here are a few things you could change to get the desired result and also make it easier for yourself to control and contain your CSS. I've added `.my-container` class to `.container-fluid` to keep the changes from applying to other pages, but that's totally optional:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
.my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-container>.middle {
  /* make middle section push header and footer at the margins of available space */
  flex-grow: 1;
  
}

.my-container>.middle>* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid my-container">
  <div class="row top">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <p>Top</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row middle">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p>Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p>Right</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bottom">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <p>Bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also:

- removed inline `style`s
- removed `position:absolute` (otherwise you'll need to keep header and footer height in sync with `<body>` or `.container-fluid` top and bottom paddings which allow all your content to be visible)
- used `flex` to position the header and footer
- removed `%` height which is considered very bad UI (consider what happens on mobile when you rotate the screen - how it affects an element with `height:15%`).

Comment: Jeez, that's perfect and ABSOLUTELY easier! Thanks so much, I'm going to follow this standard now

Comment: @TomN. It also has the advantage you don't need to worry about header/footer height. They grow as much as they need to and everything falls into place neatly. If one of them is too much, you can always have a `max-height: Xpx; overflow-y:auto;` on it, so it develops a vert scrollbar when it gets above what you want it to.

Comment: But if I want my header to be 20% height and footer 10% height, I can still do that traditionally right?

Comment: Actually, no :). Header and footer should not be expressed in `%`. Most libraries do not set `height` on them at all, only `padding` and let them get necessary height from their content + padding. Because on devices with w/h ratio bigger than 2:1, the difference between `20%` in portrait and landscape mode is too big and it simply doesn't make sense UI-wise, to set their height in `%` of parent or viewport. There's no need to make either footer or header taller or shorter than the required height for displaying their current content on current device. And it looks & feels unproffesional, IMHO.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused then: This template will just be going on a static screen, and won't be interactive. The footer will act as a news ticker with text and the top/header will house a logo, a clock and weather data. So you're saying as long as I put the height on the content, the footer/header will just adjust accordingly?

Comment: @TomN. Yep. You only need to set the top and bottom padding. Throw any content at it and it will resize correctly. Same goes for header. If you feel the need to set a height, nobody's stopping you but it's not necessary and most people don't, because they do need it to look good on more than one device.